# PHP Code not echo'ing the ban line

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, echo

Okay I'm making progress earlier i made post similar to this after people trying to help i decided to re-write my code so it's cleaner and less dis-functioned and messy.

This isn't exact duplicated this is recoded cleaner

But the problem is my Ban Line

```
echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in"><button type="button" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><strong>Oops!</strong> Your account has been banned. '.$ban.'</div>';
```

Doesn't echo when user is banned i log into my site with a test banned account it say's.

Oops!
Incorrect username or password entered!

Can someone help me fix this one little issue my code is below and a lot cleaner to get your head around.

```
<?php
if (!($user -> LoggedIn()))
{
    if (isset($_POST['logINBoss']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $errors = array();
        if (empty($username) || empty($password))
        {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter your username and password.';
        }
        if (!ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 15)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Username must be 4-15 characters and alphanumeric only!';
        }

        if (empty($errors))
        {
            $captcha = htmlspecialchars($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
            $secret = $odb->query("SELECT `google_secret` FROM `admin` LIMIT 1")->fetchColumn(0);
            $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $response = json_decode($response);
            if (!$captcha || $response->success == false)
            {
                echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Invalid Captcha Code Entered!</div></center>';
            }
            else 
            {
                $SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
                $SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
                $countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
                if ($countLogin == 1)
                {
                    $SQLGetInfo = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `username`, `ID`,`status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
                    $SQLGetInfo -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
                    $userInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $status = $userInfo['status'];
                    $userid = $userInfo['ID'];
                    $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    if ($status == 1)
                    {
                        $SQL = $odb->prepare("SELECT `reason` FROM `bans` WHERE `username` = :username");
                        $SQL->execute(array(':username' => $username));
                        $ban = $SQL->fetchColumn(0);
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in"><button type="button" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><strong>Oops!</strong> Your account has been banned. '.$ban.'</div>';
                    }
                    elseif ($status == 0)
                    {
                        $username = $userInfo['username'];
                        $logAddr = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO `loginip` (`username`,`ip`,`date`,`http_agent`) VALUES (:user, :ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), :agent);");
                        $logAddr->execute(array( ":user" => $username, ":ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ":agent" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $userInfo['username'];
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $userInfo['username'];
                        $_SESSION['ID'] = $userInfo['ID'];
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in"><button type="button" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><strong>Success!</strong> You have logged in successfully. Redirecting..
                              </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php">';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in"><button type="button" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><strong>Oops!</strong><br>Incorrect username or password entered!</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And you are sure $status is 1 when it's a banned user? You have tried to echo $status to confirm it?

Comment: status == 1 is banned , status == 0 is unbanned.

Comment: Please print the result of this: `$countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);`

Comment: Note, SHA1 should not be used for passwords. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: @Immense I know that, but have you double checked it? See here; with $status not set it returns false https://3v4l.org/dhDWv

Comment: @Andreas the code does not enter that block.

Comment: see on my old crippled code it works but the echo is getting called for Incorrect username or password entered!  echo instead of the banned user echo

Comment: @Immense again, please, tell me what this value is: `$countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);`

Comment: Please don't repost.

Comment: $countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0); it checks the database to see if the user exists if the user does exist it will then proceed with $countLogin == 1 then echo out successfully logging in which is all fine

But like stated echo under if ($status == 1 doesn't wanna echo out.

Comment: in all fairness how do you mark them ? im new ;)

Comment: I take it no one can help :(